# What is the meaning of IRAS colours?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, infrared-radiation

I came across the term IRAS colors in astronomical papers. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the Johnson photometric system ([UBV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBV_photometric_system)), the IRAS system represents a set of bands in which flux is measured by the Infrared Astronomical Satellite (hence the name, IRAS). Below are the locations of those bands, together with those of the UBV system -just for comparison-

$$
\begin{array}{cc}\hline
{\rm name} & \lambda_0 \\
 & 12 ~\mu{\rm m} \\
 & 25 ~\mu{\rm m} \\
 & 60 ~\mu{\rm m} \\
 & 100 ~\mu{\rm m} \\ \hline
U & 0.365 ~\mu{\rm m} \\
B & 0.445 ~\mu{\rm m} \\
V & 0.551 ~\mu{\rm m} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$